# Netbeans equivalent of Eclipse's LogCat for viewing Java Logs

Tags: java, logging, netbeans

I've recently used "Eclipse for Android" and found `LogCat` very helpful with it's filtering features, etc.

Is there an equivalent for Netbeans?

I would like to view Java logs from the `java.util.logging` API? It would be great to view logs and filter them by the Level, Source Class, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log Management in NetBeans is similar to LogCat. Migrate to Tools>plugins for adding this.

Comment: Hey thanks! Didn't find it in Netbeans plugins window because I'm using Netbeans 8 and it's not available there :(.

Comment: Not sure about Netbeans 8, nonetheless you can use previous versions.